# HTML/CSS how to design Node with title?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a `Node` using the `Drawflow`. I would like to create the `Nodes` something like this where I can differentiate between `Node Header` and `Node Body` something like this:

[image]

As of now, I have my `Node` something like this:

[image]

Following is [the code I have so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-matan-kvqnu?file=/pages/index.vue)

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong and how to modify the `Node` to appear as I need to?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? The bottom part should be easy, just a div with an orange border and a list or so inside.  I would just start by designing it purely with HTML and CSS and then later adding it to Drawflow (whatever that is).

Comment: See: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-goldwasser-nhk48